# Putting status codes in a Java interface

Tags: java, interface

I want need a way to get the status of a class that implements the interface. Is it considered bad practice to put the static values in the actual interface?

There would be 4 courier classes that implement the interface, all with the same return statuses.

```java
public interface CurrierIF {

    public static final int WAITING = 0;
    public static final int WORKING = 1;

    void fetch(Shipment shipment);

    List<Service> getServices();

    int getStatus();
}
```

Comment: Why not use an `enum`?

Comment: And if you also need integral values for some external interactions, you could add a method to the enum that provides the corresponding integral value.

Comment: Josh Bloch calls this the "constant interface antipattern", on top of which `int` is not a state type but a calculable type. https://dzone.com/articles/constants-in-java-the-anti-pattern-1 The other commenters are correct that this is a case for an `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

## Enum

Java has an impressive enum facility. Much more powerful and practical than the integer-with-a-label found other languages. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html).

```
package work.basil.example;

public enum CurrierStatus
{
    WAITING,
    WORKING;
}
```

When this `CurrierStatus` class loads, a pair of objects are automatically instantiated, each being assigned to one of those names `WAITING` & `WORKING`.

## Interface

Of course, an interface in Java cannot define a member variable. As an alternative, we can define a getter [accessor method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

Define a getter method `getStatus` on your `Currier` interface to return one of these two pre-defined objects.

```
package work.basil.example;

public interface Currier
{
    CurrierStatus  getStatus();

    // blah, blah, other methods defined.
}
```

In your concrete classes, define a member variable to hold either of the `CurrierStatus` enum objects. Set the status variable by injection through the constructor, or add a setter method, whatever. Implement the required getter method to return the currently held status enum object.

```
package work.basil.example;

public class CurrierDomestic implements Currier
{
    private CurrierStatus status;

    // Constructor
    public CurrierDomestic ( CurrierStatus status )
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public CurrierStatus getStatus ()
    {
        return this.status;
    }
}
```

Use it.

```
Currier currier = new CurrierDomestic( CurrierStatus.WORKING ) ;

System.out.println( "The currier status is: " + currier.getStatus() ;
```

## Abstract class

I wrote the above interface material because you so requested in your Question.

In real work, if I knew for certain that I would want every permutation of a `Currier`, every concrete class, to hold a `CurrierStatus` object reference, I would define `Currier` to be an abstract class rather than an interface.

```
package work.basil.example;

public abstract class Currier
{
    private CurrierStatus status;

    // Constructor
    public Currier ( CurrierStatus status )
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public CurrierStatus getStatus ()
    {
        return this.status;
    }

    // blah, blah, other methods defined.
}
```

Then our concrete class would extend the abstract class rather than implement the interface.

```
public class CurrierDomestic extends Currier { … }
```

…and…

```
public class CurrierForeign extends Currier { … }
```

… and so on.

By the way, try to name your interfaces and abstract classes without resorting to prefixes/suffixes to indicate an interface.  Naming is hard but worthwhile. With a well-designed set of classes, what is an interface and what is concrete should not need to be so obvious. (generally speaking)